# Split time to two variables in C#

Tags: c#, .net, time, split

I wonder how i can split a time in to two variables.

I get my time like this

```
string myTime = Console.ReadLine();
```

and if i type in 12:14 how can i do to get 12 in one variable and 14 in another?

Answer (score 10):

Parse it to a `TimeSpan` and pull out the parts that way:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("12:14");
int hours = ts.Hours;
int minutes = ts.Minutes;
```

One extra upside with using `TimeSpan` is that it also validates for you. Especially when paired with the [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparse.aspx) method, this can produce highly reliable code:

```
TimeSpan ts;
if (TimeSpan.TryParse("12:99", out ts))
{
    // the string is a valid time, use it
}
else
{
    // the string is not a valid time, handle that scenario
}
```

Comment: Much better solution than my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

By using the `String.Split()` method.

```
string [] result = myTime.Split( ':' );
string hours = result[ 0 ];
string minutes = result[ 1 ];
```